# Why does this form GET request not send the browser to the rendered view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route `get 'search', to: 'search#show'` defined for the following controller:

```
class SearchController < Application Controller
  def show
    @users = User.where( { username: params[:query] } )
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

I have a form for search at `views/application/_search.html.erb`

```
<%= form_with method: :get, url: search_path do |form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.text_field :query, placeholder: "Search users" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

It's rendered inside of `layouts/_header.html.erb` with the line `<%= render "search" %>`.

Whenever I perform a search, I get the following console output:

```
Started GET "/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=hello" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-21 18:37:20 -0400
Processing by SearchController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "query"=>"hello"}
  Rendering search/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered search/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered application/_logo.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered application/_search.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered application/_flashes.html.erb (0.5ms)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:7
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (242.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (5.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 407ms (Views: 366.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

It looks like the page is being rendered, but my browser does not go anywhere. Why is this? Currently `view/search/show.html.erb` only contains the default text generated by Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was rendered/responded as JS.

> Processing by SearchController#show as JS

You either need to respond with HTML so that browser can render directly or have some front end javascript to handle the response.

Comment: I have added a `respond_to` block, but I am unsure how to do what you have described otherwise. I have no front-end JavaScript experience. Is it possible to do this from only the form and controller?